# AEM 6.2 support for SSR & SPA

Tags: reactjs, aem, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, aem-6

And I want to build an application that needs to render in the server-side in AEM. Then I have followed the tutorial which gives from AEM [https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/getting-started-spa-wknd-tutorial-develop/react/chapter-0.html#prerequisites] . I have installed AEM 6.2 .I have two questions, I want to know AEM 6.2 support SSR ? and if yes what might be the issue for the below error.

[image]

Comment: This error coming from core component. Check your core component bundle is active or not. Also as it is clearly written that it supports 6.4 SP2 and 6.5, so why are you scratching your head?!

Comment: @Pakira Thanks for the reply. Is there any workaround to use SSR in 6.2 ?

Comment: @Pakira are you refering com.adobe.cq.core.wcm.components.core component ? This is not active It have issues when extent bundle

Comment: yes, as its not active so you cannot get it working, AFAIK, its not possible.

Comment: For sure the weekend project is built against the latest AEM versions. I think you need to upgrade AEM first.