# AEM 6.2 Local Setup Core Bundle Issue

Tags: maven, installation, bundle, aem, aem-6

And I have installed AEM 6.2 my local setup Then Created a new project using maven archetype. When I try to edit the site content of my page It gives This error.

[image]

Then I found the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169720/aem-6-2-support-for-ssr-spa?noredirect=1#comment109966694_62169720) was not installed **com.adobe.cq.core.wcm.components.core** bundle in AEM.

[image]

When I open the bundle it shows description as **A set of standardized components for AEM 6.3+ that can be used to speed up development of websites.** And it contains a couple of issues.

[image]

Then  I try to start that bundle It didn't work. I need to know what should be the issue with setup

Comment: AEM 6.2 does not support wcm core components as far as I know. Check the github page for details https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/releases

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Comment: It is not an issue - your AEM version is simply too old - wcm core has been developped for 6.3 and never aem versions.. See the official Adobe page https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-core-components/using/versions.html

Answer (score 0):

Newer maven archetypes support the latest versions. If you do not have a requirement for core components and really want to use the maven archetype for AEM 6.2, then you can try to generate your project in batch mode using archetypeVersion as 11 and set the aemVersion to 6.2.0